# Jquery animate and fade effect together

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to use animate element top and fadeOut effect together

```
 $('.img-animate-cont').mouseover(function(){
      $(".text-anim").fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 400});
      $(this).find(".text-anim").stop().animate({top:"200px"},400);
    });

    $('.img-animate-cont').mouseout(function(){
      $(".text-anim").fadeOut({queue: false, duration: 400});
      $(".text-anim").stop().animate({ top: "0" }, 400);
```

here is html

```
<section class="container" id="fourth">
            <h2 class="text-center">Latest Products</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <a href="#" class="imgLink">
            <div class="img-animate-cont">
                    <div class="text-anim text-center" style="position: relative;top:9%;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><span class=""></span>Add to Cart</button><br><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Quick View</button></div>
                <img src="slider1.jpg" width="100%" height="300px" class="img-respomsive">
            </div></a>
            <h5><a href="#">FIVE MULTICOLOR MACARONS<br></a><a><span>2$</span></a></h5>
                <a href="#" class="imgLink" id="imgLinkTop1">
                <div class="img-animate-cont">
                    <div class="text-anim text-center" style="position: relative;top:9%;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><span class=""></span>Add to Cart</button><br><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Quick View</button></div>
                    <img src="slider1.jpg" width="100%" height="300px" class="img-respomsive">
                </div></a>
            <h5><a href="#">FIVE MULTICOLOR MACARONS<br></a><a><span>2$</span></a></h5>         
        </div>
```

I want my text-anim-center div to be be postioned on my images with fade effect and if you could help with opacity background

```
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <a href="#" class="imgLink">

            <div class="img-animate-cont">
                    <div class="text-anim text-center" style="position: relative;top:9%;">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md"><span class=""></span>Add to Cart</button>
                        <br><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Quick View</button>
                    </div>
                <img src="slider1.jpg" width="100%" height="300px" class="img-respomsive">
            </div></a>
                <h5><a href="#">FIVE MULTICOLOR MACARONS<br></a><a><span>2$</span></a></h5>                             
                    <a href="#" class="imgLink" id="imgLinkTop2">
                    <div class="img-animate-cont">
                    <div class="text-anim text-center" style="position: relative;top:9%;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><span class=""></span>Add to Cart</button><br><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Quick View</button></div>
                        <img src="slider1.jpg" width="100%" height="300px" class="img-respomsive">
                    </div></a>              
                <h5><a href="#">FIVE MULTICOLOR MACARONS<br></a><a><span>2$</span></a></h5>                 
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <a href="#" class="imgLink" id="imgLinkTop3">
            <div class="img-animate-cont">
                    <div class="text-anim text-center" style="position: relative;top:9%;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md><span class=""></span>Add to Cart</button><br><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Quick View</button></div>
                <img src="slider1.jpg" width="100%" height="300px" class="img-respomsive">
            </div>

            </a>
            <h5><a href="#">FIVE MULTICOLOR MACARONS<br></a><a><span>2$</span></a></h5>                                 
                <a href="#" class="imgLink" id="imgLinkTop4">
                <div class="img-animate-cont">
                    <div class="text-anim text-center" style="position: relative;top:9%;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md><span class=""></span>Add to Cart</button><br><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Quick View</button></div>
                    <img src="slider1.jpg" width="100%" height="300px" class="img-respomsive">
                </div></a>
            <h5><a href="#">FIVE MULTICOLOR MACARONS<br></a><a><span>2$</span></a></h5>                                             
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <a href="#" class="imgLink">
                <div class="img-animate-cont">
                    <div class="text-anim text-center" style="position: relative;top:9%;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md><span class=""></span>Add to Cart</button><br><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Quick View</button></div>
                <img src="slider1.jpg" width="100%" height="300px" class="img-respomsive"></a>

                </div>
            <h5><a href="#">FIVE MULTICOLOR MACARONS<br></a><a><span>2$</span></a></h5>                             
                <a href="#" class="imgLink" id="imgLinkTop5">
                    <div class="img-animate-cont">
                    <div class="text-anim text-center" style="position: relative;top:9%;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><span class=""></span>Add to Cart</button><br><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Quick View</button></div>
                    <img src="slider1.jpg" width="100%" height="300px" class="img-respomsive"></a>

                    </div>
            <h5><a href="#">FIVE MULTICOLOR MACARONS<br></a><a><span>2$</span></a></h5>     
        </div>                                              
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="seeAll"><button type="button">See All Products</button></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

- I want my text-anim-center div to be be postioned on my images with fade effect and if you could help with opacity background

Answer (score 0):

You need to chain them:

```
$('.img-animate-cont').mouseover(function(){
      $(".text-anim").fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 400}).animate({top:"200px"},400);
    });

    $('.img-animate-cont').mouseout(function(){
      $(".text-anim").fadeOut({queue: false, duration: 400}).animate({ top: "0" }, 400);
    });
```

Not sure what your DOM looks like so might need some editing. But here's the source for my answer:
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-simultaneous-animations-on-a-single-element